# Images not loading after uploading them in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, load

I'am trying to upload a featured image in my homepage. After the upload, i got this:[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn59N.jpg)
It's not loading only on this project and not working only for images. The error.log file is empty, so i have no idea what's causing the problem. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is with your file permissions. Try setting the permissions of the uploads folder to 744, if that doesn't work, change it to 755. You will also need to set the files within the uploads folder to have a permission value of 644.